# Devise multiple model session in same browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have two devise model `User` and `Admin`. Now does devise support multiple model session in same browser in different tabs. If yes than how can i assign two different layout with two session in progress.

I tried this

```
layout :layout_by_resource

def layout_by_resource
 if devise_controller? and admin_signed_in?
   'admin'
 elsif devise_controller? and user_signed_in?
  'user'
 else
   'application'
 end
end
```

but this won't work because admin and user both already signed in.

If devise does not support two different model session in same browser then what is the purpose of using devise and how can i accomplish my requirement.

Comment: The purpose of using devise is to have authentication in your rails application..

Answer (score 0):

If you follow this  https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-Role

You can simply check `current_user.admin?`

```
def layout_by_resource
 if current_user.admin?
   'admin'
 elsif current_user
  'user'
 else
   'application'
 end
end
```